# Generating bit codes for two different cases

Tags: c++, algorithm

I need to generate bit code of some length *n*. Let say *n = 3*, then I have two different cases

1) I need to generate all bits starting with bit set *1* at position *1*

```
100
101
110
111
```

2) and bit code with bit set *0* at position *1*

```
000
001
010
011
```

and then the same procedure for bit positions 2, and 3.

I would highly appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you expect us to write the code for you ?

Comment: How about just incrementing an int ?

Comment: incrementing int would give u all cases.

Comment: @haccks, no, I expect ideas, someone might have had the same problem before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the simpliest ways is to generate set of all 2-bit lines (00, 01, 10, 11). After it you can insert 0 or 1 in i-th position to obtain necessary set of 3-bit lines. For example, if you need 'bit code with bit set 0 at position 1' you can just put '0' in first position of all these four 2-bit lines.

Comment: n can be large, not limited to 3. I need a general solution.

Comment: So, you can generate set of (n-1)-bit lines (it is easy: just use incrementing of int). After it you can insert proper bit in proper position of all generated lines.

Comment: thanks for your comment, sounds like a good solution. It didn't cross my mind :(. I was expecting something more complicated. I thought about two binary decision trees, with root 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: your description of the algorithm is recursive !

This is an example for an `8` bits sequence. It can theorically handles as many bits as you want, but the complexity is `O(2^n)`, so you will hit a hard wall for big `n`s.

Principle is to handle the 1 bit case explicitly, and to rely on recursion to handle the remaning bits. When we don't have any more bits to process we output the current sequence.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

template <class T, class T2>
void bitseq(T begin, T2 end, std::function<void()> output) {
    if(end == begin) {
        output();
    } else {
        *begin = 0;
        bitseq(begin+1, end, output);
        *begin = 1;
        bitseq(begin+1, end, output);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::vector<int> bits(8, 0);
    bitseq(bits.begin(), bits.end(), [&] {
        std::copy(bits.begin(), bits.end(),
                  std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ""));
        std::cout << std::endl;
    });
}
```

Comment: interesting solution, though I didn't try it in real code.